# "I have played football for five years."

Tags: sentence-construction

what's the difference between:

> 1- I have played football for five years.
> 2- I have been playing football for five years.

Comment: @AlexTheBN What "latter"??

Comment: 1- I have learnt English for five years.
2- I have been learning English for five years.

Answer (score 1):

So the first one (1- I have played football for five years) says that you have played football for 5 years but you don't specify if you are still playing at this moment or not.

The second one (2- I have been playing football for five years) means that you have played for 5 years and that at the moment you are still playing football

Comment: -1 I have played for five years means you are still playing it.

Comment: so what's the difference then?

Comment: I mean, you could say that, but if you are still playing is better to use the second one